# Duplicate points Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, coordinates

I am creating a line and added to the scene and shows well.

but when I try to create a mesh (using the same coordinates that I formed the line) I get errors that no duplicate points.

"Warning, unable to triangulate polygon!
Duplicate point 653.4789181355854: 204.0166729191409
Either or not infinite solutions!
Its finite solutions.
Either or not infinite solutions!
Too bad, not solutions. "

The strange thing about all this is that the coordinates are more than 4000 points, and I'm sure none of them is repeated. (I even checked in excel, and are only repeated the coordinates of start and end which I understand to be the same) .
what can I do?. no way that from the points of the line can create the mesh without me these errors appear ?. or what other steps should I follow?

```
for(var x in features.features){

     materialLinea[x] = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "#FFFFFF"} ); 
      array_extrude[x]=new Array();
     material[x] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: "#FF0000"
                }); 
     geometria[x] = new THREE.Geometry();

    for(var s in features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0]){
        geometria[x].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][0],features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][1],0))
        array_extrude[x].push(new THREE.Vector3(features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][0],features.features[x].geometry.coordinates[0][s][1],0));
    }
    line[x] = new THREE.Line( geometria[x], materialLinea[x])
    scene.add(line[x])



    object3d[x] = new THREE.Shape( array_extrude[x] );
    var extrusionSettings = {bevelEnabled: false,amount:10, };

    figuraExtrude[x] = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( object3d[x],   extrusionSettings );
    municipios[x] = new THREE.Mesh( figuraExtrude[x], material[x] );
    scene.add(municipios[x]);
}
```

Comment: you need to show the relevant code

Comment: @gaitat is ready! I edit the topic!

Comment: are you using r71? if not, can you update to that?

Comment: i am using r60.. this is the problem?

Comment: well r60 is more than two years old. you should definitely upgrade. use https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases to see the changes.

Comment: @gaitat I just upgraded to R71 but I duplicate messages keep appearing points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88040/discussion-between-user5115790-and-gaitat).

Comment: @gaitat it is not working..

Comment: I went to chat, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88040/discussion-between-user5115790-and-gaitat

Comment: @gaitat I wrote you in chat what you told me, review it please.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge vertices on your geometries
[Geometry.mergeVertices()](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry)

Comment: Add `line[x].mergeVertices();` and `figuraExtrude[x].mergeVertices();`before add these geometries to your scene

Comment: thank you but...Uncaught TypeError: line[x].mergeVertices is not a function

Comment: oups... sorry . You must add it on the geometry `geometria[x].mergeVertices();`

Comment: putting that no change occurs. still appears that there are duplicate points.